# dotnet add ProjectReference with name

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, .net-4.8

I'm trying to add a solution project reference to my current project with dotnet command line as Visual Studio 2022 may do.

Step to reproduce
On VS2022

- Create a console project solution that uses a standard .net library you've developed and add it to the solution, so the solution have 2 projects :

  - the Console project - name = ConsoleProject
  - the library project - name = MyLibrary
- Add reference to library project to the Console project (never mind if it doesn't need it)
- Inspect Console csproj project file ; it may have a section that looks like :

  ```
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj">
     <Project>{b9f7715c-9100-434e-9261-f6200d384426}</Project>
     <Name>MyLibrary</Name>
   </ProjectReference>
  ```

When I use command line interface dotnet client, I try to add such library project (MySecondLibrary) to the ConsoleProject project, I only get a reference to the path of the second library :

Command :

```
dotnet add ConsoleProject.csproj reference ../Library/MySecondLibrary.csproj
```

and get :

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Library\MySecondLibrary.csproj" />
```

in the csproj file, without the name.

I'd like the CLI works as VS does.
How can I resolve this ?

Thanks !

Edit :

Red : Used dotnet CLI to add reference to ClassLibrary1
Green : Used VS add reference to ClassLibrary2
I need to add my all references with cli on multiple projects and want all to be like the one add with VS...
Hope I'm clear.

[image: Visual Studio - solution navigator]

Comment: The version with the `<Name>` is the _old-style_ of Project-Reference, before .NET Core came out (along with _much improved_ `csproj` files!). There is no reason to use the old style. Why do you want it?

Comment: Also, FWIW, when I create a solution with projects and add references between them, I _never_ get the `<Name>` version - I always get the cleaner version. Are you sure you didn't target .NET Framework 4.6.x by mistake?

Comment: @Dai I'm pretty sure I use .net Fw 4.8. I've edited my question to add specific picture of what I want and what I don't.

Comment: Yes, but **why** do you want one over the other? What advantages does (IMO, _the far worse option_ give you?) The old Project-GUID + Name + csproj-path thing means you've got 3 redundant fields that could go wrong independently - whereas the modern-style, with _only_ the `.csproj` path is far more simpler and resiliant... (nevermind that new-style `.csproj` files don't have exposed per-project GUIDs at all anymore either, so even if you could have it your way, what GUID would you be even be using?)

Comment: @Dai Need the references to be added with CLI because of multiple projects and multiple libraries. 
I want to add those with bash shell and not with VS because it will be exhausting.

Comment: ...but what has that got to do with you seemingly wanting the extra markup?

Comment: @Dai I want to see in VS the library reference to ClassLibrary1 not as "..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" but as "ClassLibrary1"
So far like ClassLibrary2 looks.
The only difference between those two reference in ConsoleApp1.csproj file is the "Name" tag, present for ClassLibrary2 and absent for ClassLibrary1.